# How can i hide/show <ion-item> in popover?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to hide/show links in a popover based on some user parameters, for now im trying to hide the admin link if "user.isAdmin" is false. However i can't seem to make it work, even if i set *ngIf="true", or "1==1" it won't show the  i'm trying to hide. Help would be much appreciated.

popover.component.html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button (click)="profil()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Profil</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngIf="user.isAdmin == true">
    <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button (click)="admin()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Admin</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button (click)="logut()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Log ut</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

popover.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-popover',
  templateUrl: './popover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popover.component.scss'],
})
export class PopoverComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;

  constructor() {
    this.user = {
      isAdmin: true
    };

   }

ngOnInit() {}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-click="popover.hide()"` for example :

```
<script id = "popover.html" type = "text/ng-template">
    <ion-popover-view>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list" ng-click="popover.hide()">
          <a class="item" href="#/app/profit">
            Profit
          </a>
      
          <a class="item" href="#/app/company}">
            Company
          </a>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-popover-view>
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi, i'm new to both angular and ionic so i'm probably wrong but i can't see how this would fix the problem, my problem is that no matter what i put in *ngIf="" it wont show the <ion-item>, i thought it was suposed to render it if its true and dont if its false